# How to categorise a list by the date in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm trying to get the json list to be represented by the different date according to when it was uploaded

[image]

Just something like this

[image]

This is what I have instead
I'm trying to group all transaction on the same day to just have one "Today" and the one of tomorrow to just have one "tomorrow" instead of it repeating itself

```
Container(
                      //color: Colors.black,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.06,
                        right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.06,
                        top: 10,
                      ),
                      child: FutureBuilder(
                        builder: (context, projectSnap) {
                          if (projectSnap.connectionState ==
                                  ConnectionState.none &&
                              projectSnap.hasData == null) {
                            //print('project snapshot data is: ${projectSnap.data}');
                            return Text('Nothing To show Here');
                          } else if (detail == null) {
                            return Center(child: LoadingWidget());
                          } else if (detail == []) {
                            return Center(
                              child: Text('Nohing to show here'),
                            );
                          } else {
                            return ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: detaillenght,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  return SingleChildScrollView(
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          'Today',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Theme.of(context)
                                                  .primaryColor
                                                  .withOpacity(.6),
                                              fontSize: 18,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 10,
                                        ),
                                        listview(context, index, amount,
                                            description, detail),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  );
                                });
                          }
                        },
                        future: fetchlist(),
                      ),
                    ),
```

This is the code for the future builder I used

```
Future<void> fetchlist() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var token = await prefs.getString("token");
    var response = await networkHandler.get('/getalert', token);

    var data = jsonDecode(response);

    detail = data['Detail'];
    description = data['description'];
    amount = data['amount'];
    date = data['date'];

    print(detail);
    detaillenght = detail.length;
    print(date);
  }
```

this is the future function it's calling

```
 [1662392319707, 1662626801573, 1662626802691, 1662626803340, 1662626803835, 1662626829586, 1662626830965]
```

This is how the date for each list called is arranged

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Map<DateTime, bool>` variable declared in the `FutureBuilder` so you can know whether the date of the current transaction was already built or not, and in every iteration in the `ListView`, building the text only if it hasn't been built before.

```dart
child: FutureBuilder(
  builder: (context, projectSnap) {
    final builtDates=<DateTime, bool>{};
    if (projectSnap.connectionState ==
            ConnectionState.none &&
        projectSnap.hasData == null) {
      //print('project snapshot data is: ${projectSnap.data}');
      return Text('Nothing To show Here');
    } else if (detail == null) {
      return Center(child: LoadingWidget());
    } else if (detail == []) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('Nohing to show here'),
      );
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: detaillenght,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            var shouldBuildDate=false;
            if(builtDates[currentTransactionDate]==null){
              shouldBuildDate=true;
              builtDates[currentTransactionDate]=true;
            }
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  if(shouldBuildDate)
                  Text(
                    'Today',//convert the date to a text you need here.
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context)
                            .primaryColor
                            .withOpacity(.6),
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  listview(context, index, amount,
                      description, detail),
                ],
              ),
            );
          });
    }
  },
  future: fetchlist(),
  ),
```

Comment: how do I define currentTransactionDate

Comment: @CINO that's up to you. It depends on your models and how you store the data you receive from your API. I understand that you're receiving in detail some field 'date' or something like that